# Sql query with fetch by condition

Tags: sql-server

Good day to you all. Faced with a problem and I am in a stupor, please help. You need to write an sql query according to the condition: where code = 2 and num = 2 then change the value, if code = 3 then take the record whose value code = 1
[image]

```
    , a as (
       select numberfn, street
         from tbl
       where code = 2
         and nume = 2)
, b as (
    select N from tbl where code = '3'
)
, actual as (
    select b.value, a.N
      from b
        join a 
        on b.N = a.N
    where b.code = '1'
    union all
    select st.value, st.N
      from rreg st
             join tbl b
                  on st.N = b.N
    )
```

I tried to simplify it using case as well, but the second condition leads me to a dead end.

```
, actual as (
    select N
         , case when (code= 2 and num= 2)
             then value
         else .... (condition: select an entry for N where code = 1)
         end value
    from tbl
)
```

Comment: This looks to me like a copy paste from a college question without any effort to solve.

Comment: _where code = 2 and num = 2 then change the value_ Change the value to _what_?

Comment: _if code = 3 then take the record whose value code = 1_ What if there are _many_ records with value code = 1? This is a very badly worded question that makes no sense. Your lecturer should find a new job.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably misspelled it. I use MS SQL server, I need that under the condition code = 2 and num = 2, the value of the string remains, otherwise replace it with the value for the string with code = 1.Here is my sample code, but it is huge and clearly can be simplified, but how I do not know. Even separately, the parts work well, but together they do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 requirements here, one is to update, the other is to select a value.

Separately they are:

```
UPDATE  table
SET     value = ??
WHERE   code = 2 AND num = 2
```

And

```
SELECT  * FROM table
WHERE   code = 3 AND value = 1
```

(Where ?? = value you want to change the column value to.)

If you want both in one function, then they can be moved into a stored procedure.